# Replying to professor who said that I can join his research group as a PhD student next year

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

In search of a Ph.D. position, I emailed a professor and he replied me that I should recontact him next year as he does not have any available position right now. Also, he said that it will be too late for me as I will be wasting one year. Actually, deep inside, I do want to take a break of one year to spend some time with my family as I lived away from home for two years of my Master's study.

My question is, is it okay to tell professor that you want to take a long break before starting your Ph.D.? In other words, what is a proper reply to the professor who is saying that I should contact him next year?

Comment: Mandatory : [Getting over fear of writing email...](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1047)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

He hasn't made any commitment to take you on next year. I would simply write to thank him for his consideration and say that you will re-apply if circumstances at the time permit. You don't need to say more now.

Saying too much might be a mistake. But thanks should be expressed, certainly. Use the year to find another position or use it profitably otherwise. Reexamine your options if you are still available in the future.

Comment: ... because if you tell him that you intend to take a year off but you apply for another position, this has a tendency to come back to him (immediately or later) as it's a small world. Say indeed something positive about seeing yourself at a nonspecified future date in his project/group/city/... .